# Is the zero set of an analytic submersion in several variables connected?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $f:\Omega\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic submersion. Then is $Z(f)=\{z\in\Omega:f(z)=0\}$ necessarily connected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Let $\Omega:=\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$, and take $f$ to be the projection on the second argument.

Comment: Yes, this will do. Thanks.